# How to use AMQP python client for ActiveMQ

Tags: python, activemq-classic, amqp

I used [amqp](https://pypi.org/project/amqp/) client to connect ActiveMQ broker.

```
import amqp

USER = "guest"
PASSWORD = "guest"
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = '5672'

host = HOST + ":" + PORT

conn = amqp.connection.Connection(host=host,userid=USER,password=PASSWORD,login_method='AMQPLAIN',ssl=True)
conn.connect()
```

Getting error : OSError: Server unexpectedly closed connection

Comment: I am a big fan of https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ the pika library for amqp messaging. But I am assuming your local amqp is not up or might not be running properly or on wrong port.

Comment: The amqp versions supported by both programs are different.

Answer (score 1):

Pika uses AMQP 0.9 and ActiveMQ uses 1.0. These protocols are incompatible.

Read the very beginning of the [Pika docs](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Read the first line in the [ActiveMQ AMQP docs](https://activemq.apache.org/amqp).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the connection params default to the proper settings.

Try just

```
import amqp

USER = "guest"
PASSWORD = "guest"
HOST = '/'
PORT = '5672'

host = HOST + ":" + PORT

conn = amqp.connection.Connection()
conn.connect()
print(conn.is_closing)
```

If you look at the implementation of Connection() it is

```
def __init__(self, host='localhost:5672', userid='guest', password='guest',
                 login_method=None, login_response=None,
```

...

So it defaults to the correct stuff and runs for me locally using rabbit mq.

Hope this helps!